# I want to redirect through .htaccess everything that is accessed without _ (underline) to a particular page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to use `.htaccess` so that every request without an `_` (underline) will be  redirected to a particular page.

Examples:

1. domain.com/text.php to be redirected to a specific file.
2. domain.com/_text.php) to load that page as usual

Comment: domain.com/_test.php should go to /test.php right?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a rewrite rule *something* like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^_]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /my-particular-page.php [L]
```

Which I haven't tried, but it will takes every path which doesn't contain `_` and send you to /my-particular-page.php instead.

Comment: Please help me                                                                                     
page who don't have _ and have .php page redirect to fail.php